# sqlite + PyQt5 to standalone exe - Python 3.6.3 + Pyinstaller

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I would like to create an `exe` with `Pyinstaller` including a database (.db) and a picture (.png). I want everything into a **single** `exe` (`--onefile`). I tried to add the path of both elements directly in the `spec` file but it doesn't work.

Here is my `spec` file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['back_end.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\...\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\...\\Test_packaging'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=['C:\\Users\...\\Test_packaging\\database1.db', 'C:\\Users\...\\Test_packaging\\picture1.png'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='back_end',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you can add a sqlite database (db) file inside an executable (exe). Where you store the database file is up to you, but based on my experience, I would suggest to store it in some OS folder, for example: `~/Library/Application Support/<APPNAME>` (OS X) or `C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/<APPNAME>` (Windows). Please, take a look at QStandardPaths. Another tip: in your question, you said `it doesn't work`. `it doesn't work` means nothing. You need to specify what is going on, what error are you getting, etc.

Comment: My goal is to share my executable (`exe`) and my concern is if the user moves the `exe` in another folder without the `db`, that will create an error. An alternative would be to develop a complete installation process but I don't know if this can be done with `pyinstaller`.

Comment: If you use a standard path, as I mentioned, and create the database dynamically, you don't need to worry about where the executable is.

Comment: For example: when the user opens the application you must check if the database file exists in the folder: `C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/<APPNAME>`. If it does not exist you need to create it using an SQL file which is included as a resource in your application. You can use the [pragma user_version](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) to control the database version for the next releases. Note that using **QStandardPaths** the database file will always be in the same folder, no matter where your executable is. (this is only an example, there are other ways to do that)

Comment: Thank you, I understand the logic behind your explanation. As a rooky in Python, I need to do some more research but I just want to confirm one thing: The path where to store the `db`, the pre-filled `db` for the first opening, etc. those elements have to be specified in the spec file. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know. Actually, I use Qt with C++. As I understand you should pass the database path as a parameter to the class responsible for dealing with database operations (e.g. DatabaseManager), but you still need to set this path in someplace, maybe in the `spec` file is a good idea, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You have to solve many issues to get this working. For example:

- Getting the right resource path
- Adding data

The first issue is solved by adjusting paths depending on execution mode.

```py
def app_path(path):
    frozen = 'not'
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
            # we are running in executable mode
            frozen = 'ever so'
            app_dir = sys._MEIPASS
    else:
            # we are running in a normal Python environment
            app_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    return os.path.join(app_dir, path)
```

The second issue is efficiently including what you need. At first the obvious solution is to add each image and db manually, but i had lots of image. I turned to the spec file way using the wildcard operator (*) to add what i need in folder than adding `folder/*`.

```py
added_files = [
         ( './pics/*', 'pics' ),
         ( './db/*', 'db' ),
         ]
```

then in Analysis,

```
datas = added_files
```

A thorough answer is quite long. I've written [this article](https://www.pythonkitchen.com/packaging-an-sqlite-db-included-crud-pyqt5-app-using-pyinstaller/) to show in some minute details what i went through to solve the issue.