# SQLite3 db is not getting included in the compiled directory pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyinstaller

Here are my files that i have in a folder ready for compile...

[image: Files ready for compile]

After using pyinstaller i now have my compiled folder complete...

[image: After compile]

However, as you can see codes.db file is not in the folder as expected!

That is until i click the `.exe` to launch...then all of a sudden the `.exe` spits out an empty `codes.db` file showing 0kb and have no tables. I am assuming at this point that because the `codes.db` is missing the `.exe` creates an empty `.db` with the same name.

How can i make sure that my sqlite3 db is included in the compile? It needs to still have its read/write capability.

EDIT

Im using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: If this is a pre-existing database, then you need to copy it to the output directory after the build. If there is no "Copy to output folder" option in the file properties explorer, then you need to define a post-build event and copy it yourself.

Comment: It is a pre-existing database indeed. So i just need to do my compile and then copy the db in to the output directory manually?

Comment: Yes, you can do it manually, or using one of the two methods I mentioned, you can have VS do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your .spec file. Running

```
pyinstaller file.py
```

produces a `file.spec` file. This file should be edited by the user to fit his needs. One hassle free way i found is to have the db in a folder and add the folder, setting datas in analysis to

```
[
  ( './db/*', 'db' ),
]
```

You can view my complete answer on SO here: [sqlite + PyQt5 to standalone exe - Python 3.6.3 + Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114772/sqlite-pyqt5-to-standalone-exe-python-3-6-3-pyinstaller)